# What does "kittie-kittie-kittie" mean and how is it spelled correctly (in transcription)

Tags: word-requests

What does the most famous line of the movie Audition (Ôdishon, 1999) mean and how is it transcribed correctly using Latin letters?

It sounds (!) like "kittie, kittie, kittie, kittie, kittie" and is uttered, when the female character puts long needles into various sensitive body parts of her victim. The DVD-subtitles in various languages provide words like "deeper, deeper, deeper" or "pricking, pricking, pricking". Unfortunately, my DVD has no Japanese subtitles, and I can't find it translating those English words with the help of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never seen this film, but guessed you may be hearing きりきりきり (kirikirikiri). I tried typing きりきりきり into google to see what would happen, and it autocompleted to オーディション (Audition) so I think this is your answer for how to correctly write it in romaji. [Here is the google search.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E3%82%AD%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AD%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AD%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AD%E3%83%AA%20%E3%82%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3&oq=%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8A%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8A%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8A%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8A)

As for what it means, Chocolate says that it is an onomatopoeia, which [according to this giongo list](https://github.com/Pomax/nihongoresources.com/blob/master/giongo.txt#L541) possibly meaning 'a sharp drilling pain' which sounds relevant for the context.

As an aside, the 'tt' consonant in American English 'kitty' happens to sound similar to Japanese r, which I think is why you heard it that way.

Comment: 「キリキリキリ」と「オーディション」でヒットしてんのって、全部**擬音語**で、「切り」は関係ないですね・・

Comment: 訂正をありがとうございました〜

Comment: I've also heard that some people translate what was said in that scene as “Tickle, tickle, tickle!” Normally, it's supposed to be cute or affectionate, but it comes across as very horrifying in that scene.